# How to make class decorator which works correct with DI

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, decorator

I want to decorate my class

```
@params({
  url: '/books'
})
@Injectable()
export class BooksResource {
  constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) protected http: HttpClient) {}
  get() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
  }
}
```

by custom @params decorator

```
function params(options) {
  return (target) {
    const original = target;

    function construct(constructor, args) {
      const c: any = function () {
        return constructor.apply(this, args);
      };
      c.prototype = constructor.prototype;
      return new c();
    }

    const newConstructor: any = function (...args) {
      const instance = construct(original, args);

      instance.url = options.url;

      return instance;
    };

    newConstructor.prototype = target.prototype;

    return newConstructor;
  }
}
```

I tried one million variants with custom constructor but they don't work with injected arguments

Original constructor works nice

```
function params(options) {
  return (target) {
    return target
  }
}
```

How to fix it?
Playground: https://embed.plnkr.co/opnY3y/

Comment: what are you trying to do? you want to add property to the target class?

Comment: Yes it is. Generally I want to extend classes with params decorators when params will be merged. e.g.:

    @params({
      withCredentials: true
    })
    class Resource {}
    
    @params({
      url: '/books'
    })
    class BookResource extends Resource {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular is quite strict to inheritance. I'm not sure whether it will work with AOT but in your plunker you can use the following decorator:

```
function params(options) {
  return (target) => {
    const original = target;

    const newConstructor: any = function newCtor(...args) {
      const c: any = function childConstuctor() {
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
      };
      c.prototype = Object.create(original.prototype);
      const instance = new c(...args);

      instance.url = options.url;

      return instance;
    };

    newConstructor.prototype = Object.create(target.prototype);
    return newConstructor;
  }
}
```

*Note:* function names are required

**[Forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WYnfU9?p=preview)**

Comment: It works with AOT. Why "newCtor" name is required. It is because Angular uses it for DI?

Comment: @tamtakoe , Strange. I should not work with AOT since you use function expression in a decorator.